# Implementing raw input in a method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class below but struggling to make the script work as intended.

```
class firstClass:
   def test(self):
      enter = raw_input()
      books = enter.split()
      books = []
      for index in range(len(books)):
        print 'Current Books :', books[index]

mybooks = firstClass()
mybooks.test()
```

My end goal is to have a situation where if i enter `book1`, `book2` `book3` and so forth, i get a result like so ( I dont want to limit it to just three books)

```
Current Books, book1
Current Books, book2
Current Books, book3
```

Comment: What's the point of `books = []`?

Comment: What's the point of `range(len(...))`?

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `books` properly with the line `books = enter.split()`. The next line `books = []` *overwrites* this value with an empty array, so the loop never happens.

Removing that one line, it works as expected:

```
>>> class firstClass:
...    def test(self):
...       enter = raw_input()
...       books = enter.split()
...       for index in range(len(books)):
...         print 'Current Books :', books[index]
... 
>>> mybooks = firstClass()
>>> mybooks.test()
book1 book2 book3
Current Books : book1
Current Books : book2
Current Books : book3
```

As you probably know, `split()` without any arguments will split on whitespace, so this assumes that the input is entered with spaces in between. You will have to specify another delimiter (like a comma) explicitly if that is the case.

As another note, `index for range(len(arr))` is an anti-pattern in Python that should almost always be avoided. You for loop can be rewritten this way for readability:

```
for book in books:
    print 'Current Books :', book
```

Comment: Thank you brianpck. I thought including the `books = [] ` line was needed to capture the entries into a list. My mistake.

Comment: Split returns a list so that's unnecessary. You could have done that before though

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 5th line, your code will work fine.

```
class firstClass:
   def test(self):
      enter = raw_input()
      books = enter.split()
      for index in range(len(books)):
        print 'Current Books :', books[index]

mybooks = firstClass()
mybooks.test()
```